# How to setup dynamic onChange event handler?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, onchange

I'm working with a react codebase and have to pass different functions in an onChange event handler into another component that fires up dynamically. This is the code in a component managing filter:

```
<legend>Brands</legend>
            {brands.map((data) => (
              <>
                <CheckboxFilter
                  key={brands.id}
                  data={data}
                  filterByBrand={filterByBrand}
                />
              </>
            ))}
<legend>Display</legend>
            {displays.map((data) => (
              <>
                <CheckboxFilter
                  key={displays.id}
                  data={data}
                  filterByDisplay={filterByDisplay}
                />
              </>
            ))}
```

And this is another component which manages Checkbox handling:

```
<fieldset>
      <div>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name={data}
          id={data}
          value={data}
          onChange={() => {
          filterByBrand(data);
          }}
          />
        <label htmlFor={data}>{data}</label>
      </div>
</fieldset>
```

The issue is, I have to pass both `{filterByBrand}` & `{filterByDisplay}` props into the onChange event handler of the Checkbox component dynamically. But when passing, it reads both functions (`{filterByBrand}` & `{filterByDisplay}`) instead of reading dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to refactor your `CheckboxFilter` component, you don't need props like `filterByBrand` or `filterByDisplay`, rename them to `onChange` or something like, then in your `CheckboxFilter` you will get always the same name.

Also, I don't know your use case for these filters, but I guess you need 2 additional states to keep the values of selected `Brands` and `Displays`

Here is an example of how I would implement these filters:

```
const CheckboxFilter = ({
  id, checked, label, onChange,
}) => (
  <fieldset>
    <div>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={checked}
        id={id}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
      <label htmlFor={id}>{label}</label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
);

// additional hook to keep state of selected items
const useSelection = () => {
  const [ids, setIds] = React.useState([]);

  const toggle = React.useCallback((id) => {
    if (ids.includes(id)) {
      setIds(prev => prev.filter(i => i !== id));
    } else {
      setIds(prev => [...prev, id]);
    }
  }, [ids, setIds]);

  return { ids, toggle };
};

// sample data
const brands = [{ id: 1, name: 'Brand 1' }, { id: 2, name: 'Brand 2' }];
const displays = [{ id: 1, name: 'Display 1' }, { id: 2, name: 'Display 2' }];

const Filters = () => {
  const selectedBrands = useSelection();
  const selectedDisplays = useSelection();

  // selectedBrands.ids includes selected brands
  // selectedDisplays.ids includes selected displays

  return (
    <div>
      <legend>Brands</legend>
      {brands.map((brand) => (
        <CheckboxFilter
          key={brand.id}
          id={`brand_${brand.id}`}
          checked={selectedBrands.ids.includes(brand.id)}
          onChange={() => {
            selectedBrands.toggle(brand.id);
          }}
        />
      ))}
      <legend>Display</legend>
      {displays.map((display) => (
        <CheckboxFilter
          key={display.id}
          id={`display_${display.id}`}
          checked={selectedDisplays.ids.includes(display.id)}
          onChange={() => {
            selectedDisplays.toggle(display.id);
          }}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer this, Andrzej T. But, as you mentioned, I have two different states (and more) to manage. As we can guess by the names of passed props, I have to filter based on different states. How can we do this by using a single function like `onChange`?

Comment: I've updated the answer, please have a look at the attached code.

Comment: Thanks, Andrzej. I tried with this code, but it's not working. Maybe because I'm novice in React. How to refactor the above code into two separate components communicating with each other? Also, I import the values for `brands` and `displays` from another component, into the `Filters` component.

Comment: can you share an example of `brands` and `displays`? I would like to see what kind of properties they have. I guess you are passing these values as properties to Filters component, right?

Comment: Yeah, those are being passed as props to Filter Component.                                 
                                                                                                                                 
 `const brandSpec = ['All', ...new Set(data.map((item) => item.brand))];
  const displaySpec = ['All', ...new Set(data.map((item) => item.display))];

  const [brands, setBrands] = useState(brandSpec);
  const [displays, setDisplays] = useState(displaySpec);`